# Merge two cell in Docs with google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

Before start, i've searched about this topic on internet but many of the information is old, when was impossible to create a merged cell in Docs using the UI, however now it possible.

Since the google apps script support page said that i need to ask for help in this site.

I want to know if is possible to merge two cell (colspan) with the recent changes in google Docs.

Answer (score 1):

There's a [pretty good explanation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/table-cell#merge()) in the Apps Script Documentation, but the example deals with paragraphs.

Tables in Google Documents are made of TableRow objects filled with TableCell objects. You can think of a table as an array of arrays. In fact, you can use an array of arrays to create a table using the Body.appendTable() method.

TableCells have a merge() method that merges a cell with its preceding sibling cell. The text is joined with a newline.

The code for merging two cells would look something like this:

```
function mergeCellsExample() {
  //We can use an array of arrays to populate our table.
  var cells = [
    ['First cell', 'Second cell'],
    ['First cell second row', 'Second cell second row']
  ];

  //Creates an example document in your Google Drive Root Folder.
  //It will be titled "Cell merge example"
  var table = DocumentApp.create('Cell merge example').getBody().appendTable(cells);

  // Get the first row in the table.
  var row = table.getRow(0);

  // Get the two cells this row.
  var cell1 = row.getCell(0);
  var cell2 = row.getCell(1);

  // Check the contents of cells 1 and 2
  Logger.log('Cell1 contents: %s', cell1.getText());
  Logger.log('Cell2 contents: %s', cell2.getText());

  // TableCell.merge() merges the current cell into its preceding sibling element.
  var merged = cell2.merge();  
  Logger.log('Merged cell contents: %s', merged.getText());

  // Cell1 and merged are the same cell
  Logger.log('Cell1 == Merged cell: %s', cell1.getText() == merged.getText());
  // Cell2 no longer exists
  Logger.log('Cell2 contents: %s', cell2.getText());
}
```

Comment: Hi. 
I've already tried. and in fact it merge the cell, but it does not make the "colspan" effect. for example, i want a row with one cell but using the space of two cells. The merge function will remove the second cell in the row, merging the content with the first cell but in the next row i'm gonna have two cells and the table will look asymmetrical because the previous row contain only one cell using the space of one cell.

Comment: I see your point. The expected behavior would be the same as the Google Docs GUI: one cell, spanning two columns.  I would report this as a bug: [Google Apps Script Issues](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/list?can=2&q=docs+table+cell+merge&colspec=Stars+Opened+ID+Type+Status+Summary+Component+Owner&cells=tiles).

Comment: Applying `merge()` to the last cell of a row like this `my_table.getCell(0,5).merge();` in a document bound script is currently causing the related document to crash and show the error message `Unable to load file`.

Comment: It still crashes the same way the @user1063287 mentioned.