# Script Google Merge cells in a Doc Google Table

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-docs, google-docs-api

I try to do a script in order to merge 2 cells(or several) in a Google Document.Anyway the result is not so good as I expected because I have an error to refresh the page and visually the merged cell is not so long as the table [The result of the merge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v7tMi.png) and the initial table is [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E2bPI.png)

My Google script is :

```js
function onOpen() {
  // Add a menu with some items, some separators, and a sub-menu.
  DocumentApp.getUi().createMenu('Sample')
      .addItem('Fusion cellules tableau', 'mergeCells')          
      .addToUi();
}



function mergeCells() {
  var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
  for (var p= 0; p< body.getNumChildren(); p++) {
    var child = body.getChild(p);
    if (child.getType() == DocumentApp.ElementType.TABLE){
      // Assume we've already located our table
      var table = child;
      var tableRow = table.getChild(2); // gets third row
      var tableCell = tableRow.getChild(1); // gets second cell in row
      tableCell.merge(); // Merges seconde cell with first cell.      
      }
  }
}
```

So if you have an idea I will be very happy :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, that seems very frustrating. I was able to reproduce your issue, and it looks like a bug with the way the .merge() method works with table cells. The Scripts .merge() combines an element's contents with the preceding element's and then deletes that second element. This is actually different from how merging cells (in the Document) works. When you merge cells from the document it doesn't actually delete any elements, just sort of changes the display so that you can't access the "hidden" cell. If you call getNumChildren() on a row with a merged cell it still has the full number of columns.

Running .merge() on a cell deletes the second child and seems to create an unallowed table structure, which is probably why it throws an error.

By the way there is a .getRowSpan() method you can call on a cell, which returns 1 for normal cells and 0 for merged cells, however, inconveniently, there is no "setRowSpan()", so it doesn't look like you can do the regular style merge from a script.

There is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34815573/merge-two-cell-in-docs-with-google-apps-script) here from a couple years ago.

Also [here is the bug](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36759646) listed with Google. It is from 5(!) years ago. You can try to post there.

Maybe you can try to copy the contents over with the script and change the border style/width in between the cells but that seems like a huge pain. Good luck!